# What is the equivalent of getDefaultProps function using ES6 in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I was looking at the documentation for the **[DatePickerIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerios.html)** component and they use getDefaultProps() to initialize the props in the component.

```
  getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
      date: new Date(),
      timeZoneOffsetInHours: (-1) * (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() / 60,
    };
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      date: this.props.date,
      timeZoneOffsetInHours: this.props.timeZoneOffsetInHours,
    };
  },
```

What is the equivalent of that using ES6 syntax? Because I have been using:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    //equivalent to getInitialState is here
  };
}
```

should I do this.props = { } to set up my default props?

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if it helped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See this:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3725

```
class X extends React.Component {
}
X.defaultProps = {...}
```

If you are using the babel-plugin-transform-class-properties package, you can do this:

```
class X extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Video extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    autoPlay: false,
    maxLoops: 10,
  }
  static propTypes = {
    autoPlay: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    maxLoops: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    posterFrameSrc: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    videoSrc: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }
  state = {
    loopsRemaining: this.props.maxLoops,
  }
}
```

https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus